# Commenting code in try-catch, Java

Tags: java, debugging, comments, try-catch

I have such piece of code in my project:

```
try {
    downloadFile();
    unzipFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't download file!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Method `downloadFile()` trhows exception `IOException`, and method `unzipFile()` doesn't throw any exceptions at all.

Now I'm trying to debug this code, my method `downloadFile()` works fine, so I want to *comment* it and see how method `unzipFile()` works. Let's assume also that file size is 100 Mb :)

When I'm commenting line with '`downloadFile()`' I get this error:

> unreachable block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

In order to debug my code, I'm inserting line like

```
if (true) return;
```

in method `downloadFile()`, and then deleting it.

I'm sure that I'm doing it wrong way.
Could you please give me an example of how java masters are doing in such situations.
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just write a test for `unzipFile()` in isolation? Ideally a repeatable test.

Answer (score 3):

As Rob mentioned in the comments, tests test specific things/methods/behaviors. If you want to test `unzipFile` then write a reproducable test case for `unzipFile` and don't mess with anything else (ie `downloadFile`) that could have its own problems. Then, you test `unzipFile` with known input and output data.

In other words, if you want to test `unzipFile` test that, and not everything else with it.

Other than that a simple solution for you right now would be this, I think:

```
try {
    downloadFile();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Can't download file!");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
unzipFile();
```

so you can easily comment out the whole try/catch block

Comment: Oh, thanks! That's what I need!
But I've found that Java is not comfortable for doing things that I want.
For example, if I'm trying to edit code that someone wrote and I have such lines in my code - it's not to easy to quick comment one line and see, what's happening.
Thank for the answer.

Comment: Test cases are separate small methods in their own classes, that invoke objects and method in isolation from the rest of the program, are kept in a separate folder/package, and have their own runnable class. You don't test an application by commenting parts of the real/production code and then running it. Test cases are self-contained. Your program should be designed in a way that is easy to invoke and test each part of it separately. If that holds then it's easy to write a class that will build some known input, create an object that holds the method under testing and invoke it.

Answer (score 2):

If you comment out `downloadFile();`, you should also comment out the try-catch block, because it doesn't catch anything anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Why to use try/catch if you are sure that method (unzipFile()) do not throw any exception.

Answer (score 0):

The error itself says all ***"unreachable block for IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body"***.

As you said your `unzipFile()` method do not throw any exception so why to wrap it with `try..catch`? Just remove or comment try..catch() to run/debug it. That is just write `unzipFile()` in code nothing else. If `unzipFile()` depends on `downloadFile()` then it might result in error.

Comment: yes, of course - error itself says all.
I was wondering, is there any way to escape that commenting-uncommenting process. Anyway, now I know that the only way to do what I want - is to comment not only downloadFile(), but also try, catch and so on. And it's not convenient...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be commenting out `downloadFile()`.  The message is telling you the truth: no code in the try block throws that exception.

I usually use an IDE with a debugger for this sort of thing.  You can use Eclipse or NetBeans; I prefer IntelliJ from Jet Brains.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you do not need to comment anything if you have the appropriate tools. E.g. u did a mistake in unzipFile your IDE preferable eclipse will show you a stacktrace. If you click on the position in the stack trace you will automatically get the file were the error occured marking the line.

If you can reproduce this error you can set a breakpoint right before this line to inspect variables and class attributes. If you identify the block which causes the problem u can set a breakpoint right before this block and so on.